# How to Expose a Control in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm new in WPF and I'm creating a control. This control contains a DataGrid and some other WPF controls.

I created my Control as below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.MyControl" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="329" d:DesignWidth="535" >
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Margin="6,25,6,35" Name="dataGrid" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" x:FieldModifier="public" HeadersVisibility="All"/>
    <OtherControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="otherControl" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="523" x:FieldModifier="private"/>
    <Label Content="caption" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="captionLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF2626D1" x:FieldModifier="private"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So, everything goes well so far, then I create a container UserControl which has in it my control created previously:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyContainers.MyContainer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyControls">
<Grid>
    <my:MyControl>

    </my:MyControl>
</Grid>
```

What I can not do is the following:

```
<my:MyControl>
    <my:MyControl.dataGrid>

    </my:MyControl.dataGrid>
</my:MyControl>
```

I previously set the datagrid's property of `FieldModifier` as `public` in order to get access to it in another xaml, but it raises an error from visual studio.

I need to "expose" my dataGrid in order to be able to add columns and their styles.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<my:MyControl.dataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn />
    <DataGridTextColumn />
    ...
    <DataGridTextColumn />
</my:MyControl.dataGrid.Columns>
```

So, is not enough to set the datagrid's property of `FieldModifier` as `public`?

Do I need to do something else? How can I achieve this? Is this even possible?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two quick thoughts, for starter you named your data grid `dataGrid` not `DataGrid`.  Secondly, you don't add the columns directly to the datagrid, you don't add the columns directly to the grid, you add them to the `DataGrid.Columns` property, so you can try doing: `<MyControl.DataGrid.Columns>`, I'm not sure if that would work or not, I've never tried doing something like that.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I can not even access to `<my:MyControl.dataGrid>`

Comment: @Danta When you say "cannot even access" what does that mean, do you get a compilation/runtime error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @CodingGorilla it is a compilation error: "The attachable property 'dataGrid' was not found in type ...MyControl"

Comment: @CodingGorilla, Yes, it is already there

Comment: Ok, so yea you can't access a field that way via XAML, have you tried adding an *actual* public property in the code-behind that simply exposes the field?  I.E `public DataGrid DataGrid { get { return dataGrid; } }`

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes, I tried that, but it did not work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the child `DataGrid` as `MyControl.dataGrid` -- `MyControl` has no property named "dataGrid".

You might try adding a dependency property of type `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` to `MyControl`, and modify the dataGrid columns whenever that collection changes.

EDIT:
Whipped together a quick example for you:

UserControl code:

```c#
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(UserControl1));
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }


    public UserControl1()
    {
        Columns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        Columns.CollectionChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                foreach (var column in this.Columns)
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            };
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

UserControl xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
</Grid>
```

so you can use it like:

```
<Grid>
    <l:UserControl1>
        <l:UserControl1.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2"/>
        </l:UserControl1.Columns>
    </l:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```